Geometry Nodes: Array items and rotate randomly on a 90° basis
Need to array this square frame in a grid layout but they need to rotate randomly every 90° using geometry nodes.
1st image: Array i made, the one inside the green square is the main
2nd image : Reference Image from ArchDaily, its what i want to replicate
PD: first time posting here, and 0 knowledge on geometry nodes 
Thanks in advance



with this node tree:

you hopefully get what you want.
Just create a random number from 0 to 3 and multiply it with pi/2 so that you get random values for rotation (GN calculates in radians).
Then rotate your instances with rotate instances.

It did worked, but a little nitpick, the center object seems offset and doesnt perfectly stack even tho its on the perfect geometric center
https://imgur.com/a/b5XNQ25

than you made something wrong....maybe your pivot point isn't in the middle. Pls provide blend file, so that i can check it out.

You were right, the origin point was a bit off, thanks for the help
way faster than reddit lmao
